# Split object into chunks

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object:

```
var object = { '232510350': 672,
'232510352': 672,
'232510353': 672,
'232510356': 672,
'232510358': 672,
'232510359': 672,
'232510360': 672 }
```

And I want to split it into chunks of a given size like this:

```
var chunks = [
{'232510350': 672,
'232510352': 672,
'232510353': 672},
{'232510356': 672,
'232510358': 672,
'232510359': 672},
{'232510360': 672}]
```

I'm kinda stuck here since I can't use slice for this

Here's how I did it but it's ugly. I just wanted to see how to do it the right way

```
var temp = {};
var chunks = [];
var chunkSize = 3;
var amount = chunkSize;

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(object).length; i++) {
    if (i == chunkSize) {
        chunks.push(temp);
        chunkSize += amount;
        temp = {};
    }

    temp[ Object.keys(object)[i] ] = object[ Object.keys(object)[i] ];

    if (i == Object.keys(object).length - 1) {
        chunks.push(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop to loop over the properties and copy them into the resulting objects.

Comment: @Alue why cant you use slice ?

Comment: @user1692342 It only works on arrays, not objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, here it is:

```js
var object = { '232510350': 672,
'232510352': 672,
'232510353': 672,
'232510356': 672,
'232510358': 672,
'232510359': 672,
'232510360': 672 }

var values = Object.values(object);
var final = [];
var counter = 0;
var portion = {};

for (var key in object) {
  if (counter !== 0 && counter % 3 === 0) {
    final.push(portion);
    portion = {};
  }
  portion[key] = values[counter];
  counter++
}
final.push(portion);

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option using the Lodash chunk method, plus some ES6 would be as follows:

```
import { chunk } from 'lodash';

const chunkSize = 3;

const arrayFromObject = Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));
const final = chunk(arrayFromObject, chunkSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution above (not using Lodash) did not work for me. Here is an un-optimized solution in typescript:

```
export const splitObjectIntoChunks = (object: any, chunks: number = 7) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(object);
  const final: any[] = [];
  const chunkSize = Math.round(keys.length / chunks) || 1;
  const actualChunks = Math.round(chunks);
  let chunk = 0;
  let numberSoFar = 1;
  let portion: any = {};
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (chunk >= chunkSize && numberSoFar < actualChunks) {
      final.push(portion);
      portion = {};
      chunk = 0;
      numberSoFar++;
    }
    portion[key] = object[key];
    chunk++;
  }
  final.push(portion);
  return final;
};
```

Unit tests

```
import { describe, expect, it } from "@jest/globals";
import { splitObjectIntoChunks } from "./splitObjectIntoChunks";

const DATA: any = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5
};
const LENGTH = Object.keys(DATA).length;

describe("Split Object Into Chunks", () => {
  it("Using chunks >= the number of keys", () => {
    const RESULT = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }, { d: 4 }, { e: 5 }];
    expect(splitObjectIntoChunks(DATA, LENGTH * 2)).toEqual(RESULT);
    expect(splitObjectIntoChunks(DATA, LENGTH)).toEqual(RESULT);
  });
  it("Using chunks of half the number of keys", () => {
    const RESULT = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { c: 3, d: 4 }, { e: 5 }];
    expect(splitObjectIntoChunks(DATA, LENGTH / 2)).toEqual(RESULT);
  });
  it("Into 1 chunk", () => {
    expect(splitObjectIntoChunks(DATA, 1)).toEqual([DATA]);
  });
  it("Into 2 chunks", () => {
    const RESULT = [
      { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
      { d: 4, e: 5 }
    ];
    expect(splitObjectIntoChunks(DATA, 2)).toEqual(RESULT);
  });
  it("Into 3 chunks", () => {
    const RESULT = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { c: 3, d: 4 }, { e: 5 }];
    expect(splitObjectIntoChunks(DATA, 3)).toEqual(RESULT);
  });
  it("Into 4 chunks", () => {
    const RESULT = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }, { d: 4, e: 5 }];
    expect(splitObjectIntoChunks(DATA, 4)).toEqual(RESULT);
  });
});
```